# Customizing Filter Options React Data Grid

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-data-grid

How can we customize the filter options in the ReactDataGrid according to the columns?
For example I want to have only "contains" filter for name . For Date, I want to have an "in range" filter options. I couldnt find in the docs section can you please help me?

Note:
i am using $ @inovua/reactdatagrid-community  package

Comment: Which npm package do you use? Please link a code-sandbox for clarification

Comment: I uptated thank you

Comment: You need to check  filterEditor: <implement your own editor>,

Comment: Thanks a lot! I solved with filterEditor

Comment: Please mark this as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check `filterEditor:` `<implement your own editor>`